# Winrt IValueConverter on a GridView item

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime, ivalueconverter

I have a `ObservableCollection<TimeSpan> Laps` which I am databinding to a gridview. This works as expected but I need to apply a converter to set the format of the `TimeSpan`:

In my resources:

```
<utils:TimeToStringConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
```

My Gridview:

```
<GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="278" Margin="78,220,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1278" ItemsSource="{Binding model.Laps}" />
```

I have the following converter which I want to apply on the items of a GridView / ListView in Winrt:

```
public class TimeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        TimeSpan t = (TimeSpan) value;

        return t.ToString(@"hh\:dd\:ss\.fff");

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to get the converter to work, and when I apply it on the `GridView` then it is looking for me to convert an Observable collection rather than just a TimeSpan item. What should I do here ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like a

```
<GridView
    ...>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Bingo. Thank you. I attempted this the first time, assumed it was wrong, realised that instead of giving a TimeSpan object to the Convert it was actually feeding in a string strangely. I accounted for this and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below modified line

I've just modified the item source like below

```
ItemsSource="{Binding model.Laps,Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"

<GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="278" Margin="78,220,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1278" ItemsSource="{Binding model.Laps,Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" />
```

Comment: It should be {StaticResource myConverter} for his scenario.

Comment: "Cast is not valid". It is trying to convert the observablecollection it appears, rather than a TimeSpan.